# php mysql transaction process

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In web development, User request execution time is important.
Generally, it shows from how fast the page is loaded.
I have a few questions about the transaction using php-mysql.

1. In example case of inserting data to the database. Can we split the process between the insert data and the user response? In detailed, when the user request to insert data, sometimes it takes a lot of time to insert the data one by one. Can we put the insert request in the database transaction queue in server side and send response to the user directly? I ask this question because i think sometimes it is better for the user not to wait the transaction process.
2. How to make a queue in mysql database request? example like user A request to update data from database, then user B request to get the data. The requests happen simultaneously. Can we delay the user B request so the updated data can be send to user B? I read about lock database, but is it the only answer for this case?

I hope my questions are not too broad. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. You can send data to the user immediately and leave the script running until it finishes. The client will see the "loading" go until it is finished. Alternately, you can make a query queue and put queries there to be run by a separate process on the server. You can fork in PHP, but what you want is a "fork and forget" process that will spawn a zombie process. That is not a good practice. The real issue is: Why are you letting web users cram so much data in your database? It reeks of very very bad design.
2. Each query is a text string. Put the text strings in a queue. What is a queue? It could be a text file. It could be an array in memory. It could be a table in a database. It could be a monkey trained to scribble down text it sees on a teletype machine. It is up to you to decide how you want to implement the queue. Then, you have the web request write queries into the queue and your server-side process reads the queries and processes them.